# Click on image and open same image in lightbox and thumbnail , jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I use of fancybox for show image in lightbox with thumbnail image,i want after clicked on each `open_fancybox.img`, first show in lightbox, the picture was clicked. And all the pictures from the first is not displayed.

For example: if i clicked on `2_b.jpg` in lightbox and thumbnail image show(select) `2_s.jpg`.

Or
For example: if i clicked on `3_b.jpg` in lightbox and thumbnail image show(select) `3_s.jpg`.

Or
For example: if i clicked on `1_b.jpg` in lightbox and thumbnail image show(select) `1_s.jpg`.

how can change just my code, without use fancybox based?

**SEE DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/fsfucmhd/

```
<a class="open_fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a class="open_fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a class="open_fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<div class="Img" data-type="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg" data-title="manual 1st title">1</div>
<div class="Img" data-type="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg" data-title="2nd title"></div>
<div class="Img" data-type="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg" data-title="3rd title"></div>


var arr = $('div.Img').map(function (elem) {
    return {
        href: $(this).data('type'),
        title: $(this).data('title')
    }
}).get();
$(".open_fancybox").click(function() {

    $.fancybox.open(arr, {
        nextEffect : 'none',
        prevEffect : 'none',
        padding    : 0,
        helpers    : {
            title : {
                type: 'over'  
            },
            thumbs : {
                width  : 75,
                height : 50,
                source : function( item ) {
                    return item.href.replace('_b.jpg', '_s.jpg');
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use fancybox based on their documentation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox-thumb").fancybox({
        prevEffect  : 'none',
        nextEffect  : 'none',
        helpers : {
            title   : {
                type: 'outside'
            },
            thumbs  : {
                width   : 50,
                height  : 50
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/fsfucmhd/2/)

Comment: Özgür Ersil - how can change just my code, without use fancybox based?

Comment: it is fancybox based, check jsfiddle example

Comment: Özgür Ersil -I do not want to show all images at first , i just show all images in lightbox.